# If $L > 1$ is an odd almost perfect number with $\omega(L)=6$, then $L$ must be divisible by $3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, proof-verification, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

**Edited July 15 2016**

Let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of *positive* integers.

Let $\sigma = \sigma_{1}$ denote the (classical) sum-of-divisors function.  Let $I(x) = \dfrac{\sigma(x)}{x}$ denote the *abundancy index* of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.  Denote the number of *distinct* prime factors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$ as $\omega(x)$.

A number $M \in \mathbb{N}$ is said to be [*almost perfect*](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/AlmostPerfectNumber.html) if $\sigma(M) = 2M - 1$.

> By a criterion of [Dris](http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.6767), we have that
>   $$\sigma(M) = 2M - 1 \iff \dfrac{2M}{M + 1} \leq I(M) < \dfrac{2M + 1}{M + 1}.$$
>   Equality holds if and only if $M = 1$.

We now present a proof for the following *theorem*.

**(Note:  All succeeding results are only valid under the additional condition $\omega(L) = 6$.)**

> **Theorem.  If $L > 1$ is an odd almost perfect number with $\omega(L)=6$, then $L$ must be divisible by $3$.**

**PROOF**

Suppose that $L > 1$ is almost perfect.  It suffices to consider the case where we have $\omega(L) = N$, where $N$ is fixed.

Let
$$L = \prod_{i=1}^{N}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$
be the canonical factorization of $L$. (That is, the $p_i$'s are primes with $p_1 < p_2 < \ldots < p_N$.)  Assume to the contrary that $3 \nmid L$.  Then $p_1 = \min(p_i) \geq 5$.  (Note that the $\alpha_i$'s are all *even*, but it will not matter in the argument.)  By the Dris criterion for almost perfect numbers, $L$ satisfies
$$\dfrac{2L}{L+1} < I(L) < \dfrac{2L + 1}{L + 1}.$$
It will suffice to consider the inequality on the left, together with the following inequality for $I(L)$:
$$I(L) = I\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}\right) = \prod_{i=1}^{N}{I\left({p_i}^{\alpha_i}\right)} < \prod_{i=1}^{N}{\left(\dfrac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)}.$$
Consequently, we have the following:
$$2\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}\right) = 2L < \left(L+1\right)I(L) < \left(L+1\right)\cdot{\prod_{i=1}^{N}{\left(\dfrac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)}}$$
$$= \left(\left(\prod_{i=1}^{N}{{p_i}^{\alpha_i}}\right) + 1\right)\cdot{\prod_{i=1}^{N}{\left(\dfrac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)}}.$$
Now, we bound the quantity
$$\prod_{i=1}^{N}{\left(\dfrac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)}$$
by using the result that "*Odd almost perfect numbers have at least six distinct prime factors*" (which is due to [Kishore](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1978-32-141/S0025-5718-1978-0485658-X))  together with our assumption that $\min(p_i) \geq 5$. We get
$$\prod_{i=1}^{N}{\left(\dfrac{p_i}{p_i - 1}\right)} \leq \dfrac{5}{4}\cdot\dfrac{7}{6}\cdot\dfrac{11}{10}\cdot\dfrac{13}{12}\cdot\dfrac{17}{16}\cdot\dfrac{19}{18} = \dfrac{323323}{165888} = 1.949043933256\overline{172839506}.$$

This contradicts the Dris criterion for almost perfect numbers.  Therefore, $p_1 = \min(p_i) = 3$.

<s>It follows that odd almost perfect numbers greater than one must be divisible by 3.</s> It follows that odd almost perfect numbers with *exactly six distinct prime factors* must be divisible by $3$.

**QED**

**Questions**

> **(1)** By using a similar argument, it can be shown that, if $\omega(M)=6$ then:
>
> > [$5 \leq p_2 \leq 11$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3%2F2)(13%2F12)(17%2F16)(19%2F18)(23%2F22)(29%2F28)).
> >
> > [$p_2 = 5 \implies 7 \leq p_3 \leq 23$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3%2F2)(5%2F4)(29%2F28)(31%2F32)(37%2F36)(41%2F40))
> >
> > [$p_2 = 7 \implies 11 \leq p_3 \leq 23$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3%2F2)(7%2F6)(29%2F28)(31%2F30)(37%2F36)(41%2F40))
> >
> > [$p_2 = 11 \implies 13 \leq p_3 \leq 17$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(3%2F2)(11%2F10)(19%2F18)(23%2F22)(29%2F28)(31%2F30))
>
> **etc. etc.** An obvious question at this point would be: To what extent can these bounds be improved, given that the lower bound
>   $$\dfrac{2M}{M + 1} \leq I(M)$$
>   (for $M$ an almost perfect number) appears to be *best-possible*?
>
> **(2)** Traditionally, *sigma chaining* has been used to produce additional (*consequent*) factors for a hypothetical odd perfect number $O = q^k n^2$, given that $$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma(O) = 2O = 2{q^k}{n^2}.$$  Will it be possible to adapt the method of [*sigma/factor chains*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1298509) to the case of odd almost perfect numbers $M = X^2$ (where $\omega(X) \geq 6$)?  Note that $$\sigma(X^2) = \sigma(M) = 2M - 1 = 2X^2 - 1.$$

<s>*Notice that these results improve on Kishore's bounds in [On Odd Perfect, Quasiperfect, and Odd Almost Perfect Numbers](http://www.ams.org/mcom/1981-36-154/S0025-5718-1981-0606516-3/S0025-5718-1981-0606516-3.pdf) from the year 1981.*</s>