# Could a Fermat prime divide an odd perfect number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

This question is a follow-up to this [earlier post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2798459).

A positive integer $N$ is said to be perfect if $\sigma(N)=2N$, where $\sigma(x)$ is the sum of divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.  If $M$ is odd and $\sigma(M)=2M$, then $M$ is said to be an [odd perfect number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_number#Odd_perfect_numbers).  Euler proved that an odd perfect number, if it exists, must have the form $p^k m^2$, where $p$ is the special/Euler prime satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.

A number of the form
$$F_n = 2^{2^n} + 1$$
is said to be a Fermat number.  If $F_n$ is prime, then it is called a Fermat prime.

Here is my question in this post:

> Could a Fermat prime divide an odd perfect number?

**MY ATTEMPT**

(1)  It is currently unknown if $5 = 2^{2^1} + 1$ divides an odd perfect number.

(2)  Here is a [related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1939782) for the case $p = 17 = 2^{2^2} + 1$.  In fact, in a recent preprint (Dris, Tejada [2018]), it is shown that the Descartes-Frenicle-Sorli Conjecture for odd perfect numbers (that is, $k=1$) is incompatible with the set of assumptions
$$\bigg(m^2 - p^k \text{ is a power of two}\bigg) \land \bigg(p \text{ is a Fermat prime}\bigg).$$

**Updated December 12, 2018**  Said preprint has now been published in [NNTDM](https://doi.org/10.7546/nntdm.2018.24.4.18-25).

Comment: It is not known if Fermat primes $F_0$, $F_1$ etc. may divide an odd perfect number. It is known that $3\cdot 5\cdot 7=105$ cannot divide a perfect number. It is known that if $3$ does _not_ divide an odd perfect number, then that odd perfect number will have at least 12 distinct prime factors.